# How to read image files on client side PC's, "uploadedimages" folder, with .net and show them into an bootstrap table inside the app?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

**1. Explaination**

I want that the client, through the app to be able to upload CT scanner images, which for server memory reduction, will be saved on client's own pc, he will edit them and save to his pc. All the CT image data (name, surname, age,etc), will be saved through the app, on a database in the cloud and the user if it is not on his pc can access the text data though any device.

The clients folder will be on "C:\uploadedimages"

What will happen is that he/she can see them inside the app, with a bootstrap table, then edit and save them on convenience.

**2. Question:**

How can this be done?

Possibly with c#.

Comment: Sorry you are right, the app works for CT scanner image reading and some basic editing. So the user reads the image, makes its editing or notes and saves them as client's historic data where the "text part is saved on the cloud". Hope i answered your question, clearly.

Comment: It doesnt fit the needs. Can this be achieved with something like CefSharp web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Check this part in [RFC1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867):

> 8. Security Considerations
>
>    It is important that a user agent not send any file that the user
>    has    not explicitly asked to be sent. Thus, HTML interpreting agents
>    are    expected to confirm any default file names that might be
>    suggested    with .  Never have any
>    hidden fields be    able to specify any file.
>
>    This proposal does not contain a mechanism for encryption of the
>    data; this should be handled by whatever other mechanisms are in
>    place for secure transmission of data, whether via secure HTTP, or by
>    security provided by MOSS (described in RFC 1848).
>
>    Once the file is uploaded, it is up to the receiver to process and
>    store the file appropriately.

Unless the user modify the path value in `<input type="file">` manually,the value of the path shoudln't be modified,the browser shouldn't read the files in your local computer if you haven't explicity asked

Comment: Thank you @Ruikai Feng, I am well aware about the security part, but since the user has all his CT images on his pc all the time, there is no data security problem. I have to assume that there is no simple solution to this. PS: When i come up with something i will post it.